# Diferencias de comportamiento entre ejecutar el ejecutable compilado y ejecutar el programa desde el proyecto de Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Tengo un proyecto en Visual Studio. El caso es que cuando abro el proyecto con Visual y le doy a start en modo release el programa funciona correctamente y sin ningún tipo de problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando ejecuto el programa ya compilado desde el ejecutable .exe, el comportamiento es ligeramente distinto, y no termina de funcionar del todo bien.

Sé que hay diferencias entre ejecutar el programa en release o en debug, pero estoy ejecutando el programa en release, y después el ejecutable también desde la carpeta release. Por lo que debería de ser igual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las diferencias de comportamiento son las siguientes:

El programa en un momento dado ejecuta un segundo programa (CATIA) para obtener un resultado. Esto desde el modo release del Visual Studio no da ningun tipo de problema, siempre se lanza el segundo programa. Sin embargo desde el ejecutable .exe el segundo programa no siempre se lanza.

Este es el fragmento de codigo encargado de lanzar el segundo programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, ¿Porque pasa esto? ¿Puede deberse a algo relacionado con los permisos? ¿Porque el comportamiento es distinto? Y como puedo solucionarlo o evitar esta diferencia de comportamiento entre ejecutar el programa de una forma u otra.

Comment: A que te refieres con comportamiento diferente?

Comment: Hola. Haría falta que definieras ese comportamiento distinto para poder ayudarte. Lo que sí está claro es que el directorio de ejecución de tu exe es distinto si lo ejecutas desde el IDE a si lo ejecutas desde una consola o haciendo doble click con el ratón. Si tu exe depende, o buscar cosas en rutas relativas concretas, al ser diferente, igual no las encuentra. Lo dicho: Define mejor las diferencias de comportamiento.

Comment: A que no funciona igual, el programa sigue una serie de pasos, y en un momento dado, el programa ejecuta un segundo programa para obtener una respuesta. En modo release esto funciona sin problemas, pero cuando utilizo el ejecutable .exe hay veces en las que el segundo programa no llega a lanzarse. Esto no pasa en el modo release.

Comment: Podrias adjuntar lo que te dice el error?

Comment: No se muestra ningun tipo de error. Simplemente en el momento de ejecución, se ve como intenta ejecutar el segundo programa, pero no llega a hacerlo.

Comment: Y no será lo que te digo yo? Cómo hace tu programa para lanzar el otro programa? En qué directorio lo busca? Es un path relativo a tu exe en plan ..\..\Tuexe.exe? Están en el mismo directorio? Es un path absoluto en plan c:\Loquesea\tuexe.exe"? Porque como te digo, el directorio de ejecución no es el mismo. No debería comportarse distinto, así que es obvio que algo no está bien. Pero nos faltan datos para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Se busca en un path absoluto, el programa que desarrollo yo tiene unas settings en las cuales se especifica la ruta absoluta por lo que independientemente del la ruta del IDE y de la ruta del ejecutable siempre encuentra la ruta del programa. He añadido en la pregunta el fragmetno de codigo encargado de lanzar el programa.

Comment: Si el error no ocurre siempre, se me ocurre tracear el nombre y ruta así como el retorno de Start y meterlo en un try-catch traceando la posible excepción y probar hasta que te falle. A ver si averiguas algo más.

Comment: yo tengo un problema similar, en mi caso el código está en fortran y llama a otros archivos .f pero no a otros programas. Si lo corro desde Visual Studio en la versión Release el programa funciona. Pero si me voy a la carpeta de Projects, a la misma ruta de archivo donde está el ejecutable que VS me dice que está ejecutando, y abro el .exe de la carpeta Release y salta un error de cálculo (por un valor fuera de rango) en uno de los bloques .f a los que llama el programa principal.
No entiendo por qué ocurre, si en sí el archivo que se está ejecutando es el mismo, misma ruta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo.

El problema era, que cuando se cerraba el segundo programa, se quedaba un proceso abierto, por lo tanto no llegaba a cerrarse bien del todo, por eso después cuando se intentaba abrir de nuevo fallaba.

Por lo que ahora en el metedo que utilizo para cerrar el programa, tambien hago un 'kill' para asegurarme que el proceso se cierra tambien.

Esto no pasaba ejecutan-dolo desde la Release del IDE. Pero al menos ahora funciona correctamente.